# Why size of (arr[i]) is 8 byte but I see it stores 5 bytes?

Tags: c

I am confused watching this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
 
    char* arr[3] = { "geek", "Geeks", "Geeksfor" };
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        
        printf("%p\n", arr[i]);
        printf("%p\n", &arr[i]);
        printf("%ld\n", sizeof(arr[i]));
        printf("%ld\n", sizeof(&arr[i]));
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Between address arr[0] and arr[1] is 4 bytes difference (because arr[0] has 4 characters) but why when I type the size of arr[0] it says 8 bytes ?? I don't get it. When I write sizeof(&arr[0]) it also shows 8 bytes. Why ?

PS.

Why is &arr[0] and &arr[1] have 8 byte difference between each other ?

Comment: "_Between address arr[0] and arr1 is 4 bytes difference (because arr[0] has 4 characters)_": No, `arr` only contains pointers pointing to strings. It doesn't contain any characters.

Comment: Ok but it's still 4 bytes between arr[0] and arr[1] so why it says 8 bytes ?

Comment: How do you get 4 bytes?

Comment: look at the screen I've shown arr[0] is 55c969a29004 it is the address that arr[0] contains and arr[1] is 55c969a29009 it is the address that arr[1] contains. so it is 4 bytes or maybe 5 dunno

Comment: 55c969a29004 is not 8 bytes but as a number itself it is 6 bytes because 2 hexa numbers are 1 bytes there are 6 of 2 hexas so it is 6 bytes so this didn't make any sense so maybe the difference between arr[0] and arr[1] is 8 bytes but it was 4

Comment: These are the addresses stored inside `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` which point to some storage allocated for the strings. However these pointers have no relation. Each string can be placed somewhere completely different. That they happen to be close together is coincidence. None of this has anything to do with the address of `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` themselves (which are adjacent in the array of `char*`).

Comment: @Jackob2001, please edit and replace pictures of code with text.

Comment: I still don't get it. I've edited the post as well. So why char* is 8 byte ?

Comment: @Jackob2001 `char *` is a pointer, an 8-byte pointer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I wanted to show how it looks like on the compiler to better show it than say it.

Comment: @Jackob2001  Code as text, is easier to copy that a portion of a pic.  Pics attract down-votes.  Your call.

Comment: For a lot of problems we will need to take the asker's code and drop it into our tools to build it and run it and experiment on it. This can be very hard to do with an image, so you'll find a large number of potential answerers will simply move on to help someone else. [There are many more reasons to avoid images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4581301).

Comment: Then I don't get it why the difference between arr[0] and arr[1] are 4 bytes but the addresses of &arr[0] and &arr[1] are 8 bytes ? It doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: Edited the pictures with code. 
So why addresses of arrays are 8 byte from each other and not 4 or similar, and why I ask it is because if I had a pointer int *ptr pointing to a pointer *ptr2 then ptr = &ptr2 so if I type ptr + 1 then I change the address by 4 bytes but &ptr can have 8 bytes like in my arrays. Why is it like that ?

Comment: @user4581301  what do you think ? I am really puzzled why it is 8 byte difference

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof arr[i]` is `sizeof (char *)` - that is, you are calculating the size, in bytes, of a *pointer*.

Each *pointer* in `arr` points to a statically allocated `char [N]`.
The length of these strings, or their location in memory, does not factor into the offsets of each pointer in the array. Each element in the array will occupy `sizeof (char *)` bytes, and be contiguous.

The location of these strings in memory is implementation defined, and may or may not influence the location of other statically allocated objects.

---

Aside: for `printf`, the argument associated with `%p` *must* be a `(void *)`, so cast it `printf("%p", (void *) arr[i])`.

`sizeof` resolves to the type `size_t`, for which the `printf` specifier is `%zu`.

Comment: I don't quite get it char is 1 byte but char * is 8 byte ? Also I've edited the post because why &arr[0] and &arr[1] are 8 bytes ? I don't get it because if I write &arr + 1 and this is char then it moves by 1 byte but the difference is 8 bytes ...

Comment: @Jackob2001 they are very different things. `char` is a character. `char *` is a pointer to a `char`. The first is a value that (usually. sometimes it's used as a general purpose byte) represents a single character. The other is a value that tells you where to find a `char`. This is an address and, on your system, addresses appear to be 64 bits long.

Comment: So I assume that when I showed the address of arr[0] it is not the char address ? Which was 0x55c969a29004

Comment: @user4581301 `arr` is of type `char *[3]` - that is *array-of-3-pointer-to-char*. `arr[i]` is a `char *` - a pointer. I have explained (tersely) the problem with with `%p` in my answer - you must cast vararg pointers associated with `%p` to `void *` explicitly. The line invokes UB, but it is closer to correct than your description, which is confused.

Comment: @Oka Fork. You're right. I didn't read closely enough.

Answer (score 2):

The size of a pointer in C language is platform dependent. For example, when you're using a 32-bit computer, the size of a pointer is 32-bit, i.e. 4 byte, by default; when you're using a 64-bit computer, the size of a pointer is 64-bit, i.e. 8 byte, by default.

More: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof

Comment: The size of a pointer tends to follow the bit width of the computer, yet there are many exceptions.  Also the size of an object pointer readily differs from a function pointer size.

Comment: And careful with byte. I've had the pleasure of playing with systems where the byte was 32 bits.

Comment: (a) “32-bit computer” and “64-bit computer” are not well-defined terms. A computer may have diverse sizes for its registers, bus width, instruction size, bits in its address space, and more. (b) I have used one computer which ran both “32 bit” and “64 bit” programs. (c) I have used a C implementation with 32-bit pointers on a computer with 64-bit addresses. (d) The C standard permits different types of pointers to have different sizes in one C implementation.